# Create a new MySQL user in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

How do I create a new MySQL user in XAMPP? Also, can I delete the existing “root” user?

Answer (score 12):

It's too late but I'm sure my answer will help the community.

1. To create a new mysql user in XAMPP you need to type the following commands:

```
mysql -u root -p
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
\q
```

This command grants the user all permissions.For more information about setting MySQL database permissions, please visit https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html.

2. To delete MySql user definitively you should run this command

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user 
WHERE  user = 'root' 
     AND host = 'localhost';
```

Hope that it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Felix. That's great info. Welcome aboard :-)

Answer (score 1):

**XAMPP**

sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p

Enter Your Super Secret Password

CREATE USER 'UserName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'UR@Secret@Password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'UserName'@'localhost';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

**Native MySQL Client (Not XAMPP / LAMPP)**

sudo mysql -u root -p

Enter Your Super Secret Password

CREATE USER 'UserName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'UR@Secret@Password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'UserName'@'localhost';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score -1):

For me below configuration worked. Its for LAMPP:

-Create a new database named "dvwa" from http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php.

-And then inside DWVA nano config.inc.php file. Make "db_password field" empty. (ex. '').

-restart the apache as well as mysql from xampp